# in mysql is there a way to make load data infile ignore the bom?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, csv, load-data-infile

I checked mysql site, and there seem to be a bunch of people talking about this but no solution its been yet provided. The problem is that MySQL takes the BOM as part of the csv contents, which leads to unpredictable results.

I dont want to strip the BOM myself because I got very big files (lots of GB) and several of them. Any advices about a good tool if no answer will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

check below see if can solve the byteordermark problem
http://forge.mysql.com/worklog/task.php?id=2637

1. use the "BYTEORDER" clause
2. "SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE does not generate BOMs. "